# Convert List<string> to a stream

Tags: c#

The problem I have is that I have a CSV file full of records, that currently is being mapped to a strongly typed collection via the open source `CsvHelper.CsvReader.GetRecords<T>` method. It gets passed a GZIP stream which is built on a `FileStream` so is reading the stream from disk.

My suspicion is that the `CsvHelper` class when used with a `FileStream` is not very efficient as this load takes a long time. I want to try and load the raw file efficiently first just into memory, and then do the strong type mapping afterwards.

Unfortunately, the mapping class `CsvHelper.CsvReader.GetRecords<T>` accepts only a stream. I have managed to load the raw data into a `List<string>` very fast, however I now cannot figure out how to "streamify" this to pass to the mapper. Is this something I can do or is there another solution?

My code so far is

```
var fileStream = ...
var gzipStream = new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
var entries = new List<string>();
using (var unzip = new StreamReader(gzipStream))
    while(!unzip.EndOfStream)
         entries.Add(unzip.ReadLine());

Parse(??);

        public IReadOnlyCollection<TRow> Parse(Stream stream)
        {
            Func<Stream> streamFactory = () => stream;
            var results = ParseCsvWithConfig <TRow>(streamFactory, _configuration).AsReadOnly();
       }

 public static IEnumerable<T> ParseCsvWithConfig<T>(Func<Stream> streamFactory, CsvConfiguration configuration)
        {
            using (var stream = streamFactory())
            {
                var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
                using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, configuration ?? new CsvConfiguration()))
                {
                    return csvReader.GetRecords<T>().ToList();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Read the file into a MemoryStream and pass that instead of the filestream. You can use stream.copyto methods to achieve this (filestream to memorystream).

Comment: I tried that first actually, but you cannot read a gzipstream into a memorystream as the decompressed stream is a different length

Comment: *My suspicion is that the CsvHelper class when used with a FileStream is not very efficient*, based on what did you make that assumption? It doesn't make much sense as opening a file using `FileStream` is pretty much standard. If that's really the case, then it's not used properly (a bug). Since it is open source, have a look at how they did it to see if there is any obvious issue. Otherwise, you could be wasting your time and the issue is actually with the `CsvReader`.

Comment: @NZJames - not so. You dont have to give memorystream a size, it will just grow. See nvoigt answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip the list altogether:

```
var fileStream = ...
var gzipStream = new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

gzipStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

// call Parse on memorystream
```

Feel free to add `using` blocks where appropriate in your code.